# Using Delphi object constructors on preallocated memory

Tags: delphi

In C++, there exists an inplace-new operator to create an object using preallocated memory. Is there an equivalent option in Delphi?

Comment: Something similar or perhaps duplicate, [Is there a generic “Object Pool” implementation for Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16404051/576719) and [Boosting Work Classes with a mini Object Pool](http://www.delphitools.info/2013/09/26/boosting-work-classes-with-a-mini-object-pool/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent (that I know of), but you can achieve much the same effect (controlling how and where memory for an object type is allocated) by overriding the [NewInstance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TObject.NewInstance) class function in your custom class and providing an implementation, which provides the space for the new instance from a custom heap pool.

Comment: Well, the idea was a flexible way to create any class on memory already allocated by an external allocator (which can call a callback function for destruction). NewInstace overrides can't provide this. But if there is no other chance I'll try it.

Comment: NewInstance can do that but it requires a rather messy way to get the address of the pre allocated memory to NewInstance.